# Lumen Storage - FileNotFoundException

Tags: laravel, filesystems, lumen, facade, flysystem

I added `flysystem` to Lumen so I can use the `Storage` Facade.

I added the correct `config` file and then I'm trying:

```
$template = Storage::get(storage_path('a.html'));
```

Config:

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path(),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    ],
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path(),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

I'm getting:

> FileNotFoundException /var/www/storage/a.html
>
> The file exists in that location.

Any clues?

Comment: Can you provide an image showing the file in that location and can you also post your config file details?

Comment: file location https://imgur.com/a/oFb6VNa .   I added config in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Storage::get(“a.html”)` instead